# Google sheet dynamic value pivot table

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, dynamic, pivot-table, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to get a pivot table, where I can select the values from something like a slicer.

I found out that using GETPIVOTDATA can get the trick with a dropdown list, but not very usefull since it's only 1 cell.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: Here is a link with explanations of what I want : 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p4tQ2-qIQKhoi-IB47XQOmDndHskLUskkhisEysLHeY/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY({A2:A8, INDIRECT(
 ADDRESS(2, MATCH(D10, 1:1, 0))&":"&
 ADDRESS(8, MATCH(D10, 1:1, 0)))}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1
  label sum(Col2)''", 0)
```

[image: 0]